# OpenGL - Moving Camera forward

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, camera, glut

Below is my code that lets me to move the camera forward it works fine but i always want to know if I'm writing code in a efficient way..

```
void keyboard (unsigned char key, int x, int y) {

    if (key=='w')
    {
    float xrotrad, yrotrad;
    yrotrad = (yrot / 180 * 3.141592654f);
    xrotrad = (xrot / 180 * 3.141592654f); 
    xpos += float(sin(yrotrad))* 3 ;//move forward and initialise speed
    zpos -= float(cos(yrotrad))* 3 ;
    ypos -= float(sin(xrotrad))* 3 ;
    }
```

OK this question just came to my head: Does anyone know any good OpenGL collision tutorials online.. if yes would be more than grateful if u share..

Thanks for reading my question

Comment: First of all, cool down. Second, people like good questions, not random thoughts. Your question title says moving forward, then you begin with I already have the code but is this good? Then you ask a question that **just** came to your mind. The very least that this shows is that you didn't do the smallest research yourself before asking (since the question **just** came to your mind). People would like it if you researched a bit before asking.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but you have to remember what the rep system is for--rewarding good questions and answers and penalizing poor questions/answers.  Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more information on what is considered a good question.

Comment: [Insulting people isn't tolerated](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette) here, please keep discussion civil.  This isn't a forum to post any code you find useful.  Per the FAQ, this is a question and answer site.  You should phrase questions such that they are *specific* and *answerable*.  Posting a miscellaneous snippet of code along with an unrelated question is not a good candidate for a question.

Comment: @LedK: Along those lines if you are looking for feedback on efficiency or general coding guidelines a great companion site to SO is [CodeReview SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).  You can be a bit more freeform there, although make sure to read their posting guidelines before asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is pretty good. I've used similar solutions to that problem in the past. I would combine the / 180 and the multiply by PI into a constant.

## define PI_OVER_180 (3.141459f / 180f)

This should guarantee you don't have to perform that calculation every time if the constant expression is performed by the preprocessor or compiler.